# Flex Native Local Notifications

Tags: apache-flex

I've an air app that needs to put a notification on the status bar on android devices like "2 New Tips" etc. Rest everything works fine, but I am not able to find something that can put a notification on the status bar. A simple demo that puts some text on the status bar on a button click.
I really need it, as this is the last thing left in my app. Please help!!

Comment: Check https://code.google.com/p/flex-toasterlib/

Comment: Hi, appreciate the help :), but i think toasterlib is a notification that comes over the application screen as a message or error. What I want is a Notification On Android notification bar in a mobile device. So that when the application is minimized and the database gets a new record inserted I can show a notification on the notification bar. I'm done with everything in the app apart from the notification part! Please reply.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to make Native Extensions. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html

Comment: Native Extensions are the way to go.  Getting the native extension set up is by far the worst part...  But once you get that working the actual Android code is dead easy to write.

Comment: Thanks csomakk! Was looking for something like this only. Let me work on it. :)

Comment: i wish you the bests! ANE is not the easiest.